# Vue 2 / Laravel | How to give facebook robot access within the secured app?

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, vue.js, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I need to have inner pages of an app shared to facebook with the right Opengraph data but i'm presuming when a facebook **scraper**/robot tries to access a certain secured url by JWT-tokens (tymon's), it lands to the sign-in page instead and picks the OG data from there.

I'd rather need to allow access to facebook **scraper** to bypass login and reach the page to get the certain info on that page?

Comment: The Facebook scraper can be recognized by the User-Agent it sends, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1748179212062572, so you can add an exception to your mechanism based on that. Be aware though that this will mean every other client that sends that same User-Agent would also get access without login.

Comment: Plus, you should consider whether sharing stuff that is hidden behind a login makes sense in the first place. I see a link in my news feed, looks interesting, so I follow it - only to be told that I do not have access, or have to register for something first ... frustrating user experience! Not saying it can’t make sense ever (maybe links are posted into a closed group, where all members are also users of your site, sth like that) - but just plain public sharing might not be a good idea.

Comment: yes, thanks i read fb faq already and read i need to allow multiple UA to the restricted area, i'm still figuring out how would i do it the easiest / quickest way in laravel backend / vue frontend. 
since where i want to give the access is a vue front end, secured by jwt-token.

Comment: Vue is JavaScript, Facebook scraper doesn’t care about JavaScript. Your server must return an HTML document that contains the relevant OG meta data.